# I want to hash this password with salt but it doesn't give me the same answer with i hash it directly

Tags: sql-server

I want to Hash a password using salt with `MD5` but it doesnt work

I have tried changing the function a lot

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_SaltHash] (@Password  varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar ( 100) 
AS
begin
    Return Hashbytes('MD5','admin')
END

select  dbo.Fn_SaltHash('admin')
select  Hashbytes('MD5','admin')
```

`!#/)zW¥§C‰JJ€Ã` the first select

`0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3` this is what can't my function to return and this is the result of the second select

Comment: Why your function return `varchar ( 100)` instead of `VARBINARY`?

Comment: Where is your salt?

Comment: Thanks the varbinary thing really heloed me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RETURNS variable type should be VARBINARY(100) not VARCHAR(100)

Comment: may i ask why ?

Comment: The output of HASHBYTES is VARBINARY (hex) and not VARCHAR string data